# Select2 - Disable submit button when no matches found

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 to query a database and return the values. When the user types in a value that is not in the list, the no matches found message is shown. When that happens I also want to disable the submit button so the form can't be submitted .

```
<form>
    <input id="select2" type="hidden" name="optionvalue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#select2').select2({
        ajax: {
          url: "selections.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function (term, page) {
            return {
              q: term
            };
          },
          results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data };
          }
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is set the return data to a variable, and check if results exist, then, if no results came back (empty variable), disable the submit button. First, give your submit button an id, say `subBtn`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select2').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "selections.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
                if (!term) {
                    $("#subBtn").prop("disabled",true);
                } else {
                    $("#subBtn").prop("disabled",false);
                }
                return {
                    q: term
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return { results: data };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The button is disabled as soon as the select is clicked and it stays disabled after a suggestion is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you could use simple javascript to say:

```
function disable_button(buttonid) {
document.getElementById(buttonid).style.display = "none";
```

Then use the function like this:

```
disable_button(select2);
```

This will hide the button, so it cant be clicked anymore. You can write a function which will show the button again like:

```
.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: You don't have to hide the button, you can just `disable` it if they want it still visible.